# Flutter LinearProgressIndicator doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been learning flutter for a while and got stuck with a not working ProgressIndicator. The problem is that it doesn't detect any error, and progressbar doesn't update anyway when you enter a password into TextFormField. And if you have any comments about the code itself, I'd love to read it and learn something new

```
import 'RegisterThree.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegisterSec extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterSec({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterPage2 createState() => _RegisterPage2();
}

class _RegisterPage2 extends State<RegisterSec> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // regular expression to check if string
  RegExp pass_valid = RegExp(r"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)");
  double password_strength = 0;

  bool validatePassword(String pass) {
    String _password = pass.trim();

    if (_password.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        password_strength = 0;
      });
    } else if (_password.length < 6) {
      setState(() {
        password_strength = 1 / 4;
      });
    } else if (_password.length < 8) {
      setState(() {
        password_strength = 2 / 4;
      });
    } else {
      if (pass_valid.hasMatch(_password)) {
        setState(() {
          password_strength = 4 / 4;
        });
        return true;
      } else {
        setState(() {
          password_strength = 3 / 4;
        });
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 75),
            SizedBox(
                child: Text(
              'Create a new password',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            )),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return "Password";
                  } else {
                    //call function to check password
                    bool result = validatePassword(value);
                    if (result) {
                      // create account event
                      return null;
                    } else {
                      return "Password should contain Capital, small letter & Number & Special";
                    }
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(), hintText: "Password"),
                obscureText: true,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Confirm password',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                value: password_strength,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                minHeight: 5,
                color: password_strength <= 1 / 4
                    ? Colors.red
                    : password_strength == 2 / 4
                        ? Colors.yellow
                        : password_strength == 3 / 4
                            ? Colors.blue
                            : Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                child: Text(
              'Password should contain Capital, small letter & Number & Special',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 131, 131, 131),
                fontSize: 13,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            )),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            SizedBox(
                child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: password_strength != 1
                  ? null
                  : () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => RegisterThree()));
                    },
              child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, color: Colors.white),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: CircleBorder(),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                primary: Colors.blue, // <-- Button color
                onPrimary: Colors.white, // <-- Splash color
              ),
            )),
            SizedBox(
              height: 280,
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
              },
              child: Text(
                'Go back',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is that currentState is null. It is null because you have to wrap your TextFormField in a form. And to this form you have to pass the formKey, not the Container

```
Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: ...
```